# Is "continue my imagination" OK?

Tags: grammar

I am imagining something and someone interrupted my imagination. After I finish talking with him, I want to "resume my imagination/resume imaging/continue imagining/continue my imagination". Are these four expressions correct?

Comment: When you say _imagination_ do you actually mean something like _visualising_? That would make more sense to me.

Comment: Yes. I just looked up "visualize" in the dictionary. That's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

The word "imagination" only refers to the ability to imagine things, not the act of imagining, so of your four guesses, only "continue imagining" is correct for the meaning you intend.

The verbs "resume" and "go back to" fit the context better than "continue".

Also, the verb "imagine" usually has a direct object, so better to say, "go back to imagining *something*"

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think yes except for type with gerund. There must be infinitive after verb "continue" Not gerund